# Async read approach for large datasets

Tags: xamarin, realm

OK, so Realm (.NET) doesn't support async queries in it's current version. 
In case the underlying table for a certain `RealmObject` contains a lot of records, say in the hundreds of thousands or millions, what is the preferred approach (given the current no async limitation)?

My current options (none tested thus far):

1. On the UI thread use `Realm.GetInstance().All<T>` and filter it (and then enumerate the IEnumerable). My assumption is that the UI thread will block waiting for this possible lengthy operation.
2. Do the previous on a worker thread. The downside would be that all `RealmObject's` need to be mapped to some auxiliary domain model (or even the same model, but disconnected from Realm) because realm objects cannot be shared/marshaled between threads.

Is there any recommended approach (by the Realm creators, of course)? I'm aware this doesn't completely fit the question model for this site, but so be it.

Comment: Are you sure that Realm objects cannot be accessed outside of the thread they originated from? I can see it having a requirement that all reads/writes be synchronized to a single thread - but once in memory it shouldn't matter at all. It's just heap memory at that point (and heap memory is by definition not thread-affine).

Comment: @KeithRome: Good question. I need to try this first before I can answer it. Their documentation states that `RealmObjects can only be used on the thread on which they were created` (https://realm.io/docs/xamarin/latest/#passing-instances-across-threads), so that could mean anything.

Comment: Realm objects map directly to their memory-mapped original data, so using across threads is a lot harder than simple POCO (it is also why they are so fast).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realm enumerators are truly lazy and the `All<T>` is a further special case, so it is certainly fast enough to do on the UI thread.

Even queries are so fast, most of the time we recommend people do them on the UI thread.

To enlarge on my comment on the question, RealmObject subclasses are *woven* at compile time with the property getters and setters being mapped to call directly through to the C++ core, getting memory-mapped data.

That keeps updates between threads lightning fast, as well as delivering our incredible column-scanning speed. Most cases do **not** require indexes nor do they need running on separate threads.

If you create a *standalone* RealmObject subclass eg: `new Dog()` it has a flag `IsManaged==false` which means the getter and setter methods still use the backing field, as generated by the compiler.

If you create an object with `CreateObject` or you take a standalone into the Realm with `Realm.Manage` then `IsManaged==true` and the backing field is ignored.

Comment: This makes sense, thanks. I've read about the speed induced by using memory-mapped files. Will give it a try soon.